# when AWS S3 bucket modified then can i trigger local system database using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to execute the query in my local SQL database while AWS s3 bucket insert, update or delete any file.
Can I do this in .Net? Or if not then  maybe is there any way that I can call my local web API from AWS so that way I can also execute the query in my Local DB

Comment: You can check S3 event notification from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket modified"? Do you mean "when an object is added/deleted"? Also, what do you mean by "trigger my local SQL database"? Is the database on your own computer on the Internet? Is it publicly accessible? What do you mean by "trigger"? Feel free to Edit your Question to provide more details.

Comment: hi, john I have edit the question for more clarification. please check.